# How to domain/filter PO based on user allowed branch in odoo

Tags: odoo, python-3.8, enterprise, erp, odoo-14

I want to display PO based on allowed branch in odoo. So if you log in as user Ana with allowed branch = Singapore, then the PO that appear are only PO with the Singapore branch. Maybe someone knows and can give advice?

Thanks

Best Regards

Comment: Without programming but only configuration you can do that by using Odoo's security system. You have to create you own security record rules (ir.rule) and you probably need to create a new security group (res.groups). Good starting point is the [official documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/backend/security.html).

Comment: I want to implement it programmatically, but thanks for the information

Comment: Why isn't that programmtically?

Comment: Owh sorry, I thought it was manual configuration on the odoo website, and no coding required

Comment: It would be without "real" programming. You have to create the correct odoo domains for the needed record rules (ir.rule). Please look into the doc, linked in my first comment to understand the security concept of Odoo and of course the here named record rules.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the domain field on a model to filter records based on certain criteria. This can be useful for restricting which records are visible to a user based on their allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Another alterative to make a custom domain (maybe dificult because you need to access the current user)

I think you can define a new security rule, to discard PO with no match in the branch. but not sure if you can do `user.branch_id` or some other field distinct od id.

```
<record id="branch_po_rule" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name">PO own branch</field>
        <field name="model_id"  ref="model_purchase_order"/>
        <field eval="True" name="global"/>
        <field name="domain_force">('branch_id','=',user.branch_id))]</field>
    </record>
```

But security rules are meant to do this kind of discriminations

Comment: Thanks for answering and giving advice! Actually i have solved it by giving the domain like this = ['|',('branch_id', 'in', user.branch_ids.ids), ('user_id','=', user.id)]